# How is the Star Player determined?

Tags: brawl-stars

After each match of Brawl Stars, one of the players on the winning team is a Star Player.

Depending on what in-game statistics is this determined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Star player is based completely on most damage dealt by the winning team. If you lose a match, you cannot get star player, but if you win, whichever team member that dealt the most damage will earn star player, and will earn you an extra 10 experience. Becoming star player does not give you a star token, but winning a 3v3 does, or getting in the top 2 teams of duos, or top 4 of solos in showdown mode.

Comment: Someone lost but got a star player. You can search it on the web.

Answer (score 1):

A "Star Player" is determined on the team when the player wins, and how much damage they did. For example:

**TEAM A: Shelly, Colt, Rico**

**TEAM B: Piper, Leon, Bull**

Team A won, and this is how much damage the star player did:

**Shelly's Damage: 24124**

**Colt's Damage: 32953** *-STAR PLAYER-*

**Rico's Damage: 10356**

The star player is Colt, because he did the most amount of damage.

## Sudden Deaths/Draws

Imagine you lose in a draw and the star player is either on your team or on the enemy team. It's the same thing! It depends on the total amount of damage you do over the teams. Try your best to get the most damage on your side.

---

P.S.: Brawl Stars has updated, so they are not any more tickets required to play regular matches or special events.
Thanks!